# Retrieve list of members in channel discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, discord.py

## Summary

I'm really new to discord.py and am trying to figure out how to retrieve a list of people in a discord server channel. I'm working on a command that would randomly separate the channel into two different calls, but I am wondering how I would retrieve the members in a voice channel, create a list of the members, randomly split them, and lastly move the members.

#### My main concern right now is just retrieving a list of members into a list [] format

---

## this is what I have so far:

```
async def team(ctx):
    team_select = [discord.VoiceChannel.members(ctx.guild.channels, id=742871631751282829)]
    print(team_select)
```

^ this code, which I'm using to gives me the error: "TypeError: 'property' object is not callable"

Comment: `https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.members` is not a function. You may be using the wrong API

Comment: maybe you should rather use `get_channel(id)` and later get `.members` - like `team_select = ctx.guild.get_channel(742871631751282829).members`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [discord.utils.get](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/async/api.html#discord.utils.get). Here is an example. you can also use
[await bot.fetch_guild(guild_id)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot%20fetch_guild#discord.ext.commands.Bot.fetch_guild)
to get the guild object instead of `ctx.guild`

Note: bot.fetch_guild require you to use `discord.ext.commands`

```py
@bot.command()
async def voice(ctx):
    VC = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, id=705524214270132368)
    print(VC.members)  # each user is a member object
    for user in VC.members:
        # Code here
        print(user.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by [`VoiceChannel.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.members), but some things should be changed from **`Abdulaziz`**'s answer.

### **1.Use [`Bot.get_channel()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_channel)**

- Use [`bot.get_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_channel) if you have channel's ID or [`Guild.get_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_channel) if you know in which Guild the channel is and have its ID, [`utils.get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get) should be called only when you don't have ID.
- get_ methods are O(1) while utils.get is internally a for loop,
  therefore O(n).
- If you're not familiar with big O notation, O(1)
  means operation time is the same with any number of items while O(n) is linear, the more items there are, the longer it takes.
- Read more about `O(n) vs O(1)` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40293751/choosing-on-over-o1-when-for-all-of-n-o1-is-faster-than-on).

### **2. Use [`Bot.get_guild()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_guild)**

- [`fetch_guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.fetch_guild) is an API call and can get your bot rate-limited soon while [`get_guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_guild) is not an API call.
- Using the Guild object returned by [`fetch_guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.fetch_guild) will not give you the guild's channels.
- Read more about it in the documentation [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.fetch_guild).

**Here is the revised code:**

```py
@bot.command()
async def team(ctx):
    vc = ctx.guild.get_channel(742871631751282829)
    await ctx.send("\n".join([str(i) for i in vc.members]))
```