# Discord.py get user minutes in vc

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm trying to code a discord bot with discord.py rewrite, but I can't find an answer to see user vc time. How do I get this?

Comment: interesting question... you could probably run a check every now and then using some ideas from this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63367489/retrieve-list-of-members-in-channel-discord-py-rewrite

Comment: This question could be much better received if you showed effort for solving the problem on your own

Comment: @Ironkey I was thinking that I could get the time the user logs in the vc and then get the time they log off and get the time in between, but how do I get join vc time and leave vc time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`on_voice_state_update()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=voice_state#discord.on_voice_state_update) event to track users joining & leaving channels, and then store the timestamps of joining & leaving in a database or json file. Then, the time spent in each channel is `leave` - `join`.

Comment: How do I see when the user gets in the channel? The documentation didn't say about that.

Comment: you need to use datetime `now = datetime.now(); current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")`

Comment: Do you mean the timestamp of joining? In that case, that's just the current timestamp at the moment when the event is triggered.

Comment: So just let it remember when a user's voice channel becomes from None to something else as the get in time and when it becomes from that to None to be the get out time?

Comment: Yeah. Or when it changes to a different channel ID when they moved to another channel instead of leaving, then it's both leaving for the first channel & joining for the second channel.